# Assembly char* linked

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I am writing code in C and Assembly x86-64bit, I compile on Ubuntu 16.04 using NASM and gcc.

I have a label in assembly called _sum.
I call _sum and send a char* containing number only (for example: "87") and it is received by the register "rdi".
When I perform the following:

```
mov rbx, [rdi]
inc rdi
mov rcx, [rdi]
```

I notice that register rbx contains the hex value of all the digits linked together, (in the previous example: rbx has 0x3738 and rcx has 0x37).
How can I make it that each time [rdi] contains only the value of the current digit (0x38) and not all the digits linked?

Comment: If you check the smaller registers `BL` and `CL`, they will contain one byte each.

Comment: your `char` type is 8 bit wide, so use 8 bit wide instructions to work with it. `mov bl,[rdi]` or `movzx ebx, byte [rdi]`, depends what you want to end with (8 bit value or 64 bit value).

Answer (score 2):

If you use 32- or 64-bit move to register, you'll definitely get values of 4 or 8 bytes starting with the pointed byte, not only a requested one. The simplest variant is to use zero padding extension instruction, like:

```
movzx ebx, byte [rdi]
```

Note that filling ebx with some value automatically causes clearing of upper 4-byte half of rbx, so, this is the same as calling `movzx` to `rbx`. But, sign-extension requires an explicit `r**` argument.

There are alternatives, like:

```
xor ebx, ebx
mov bl, [edi]
```

or:

```
mov bl, [edi]
and ebx, 0ffh
```

but all they are less efficient on any modern processor.

Comment: `movzx ebx, [rdi]` will not compile with NASM, as this instruction needs explicit specification of source operand size, like `movzx ebx, byte [rdi]`. Without that the assembler could only guess, which `movzx` variant you did wish for (8 or 16 bit read).

Comment: @Ped7g thanks, added qualifier - I usually work with AT&T syntax and don't remember such details.

Comment: @Netch : Probably because in AT&T syntax **if** you postfix the instruction with `l`, `b`, `q` etc the size can be inferred from that too.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, AT&T uses instruction suffixes; moreover, it doesn't support all this "byte ptr" stuff.

Comment: I find that suffix adding over-verbose for every instruction, then again `gas` will survive even suffix-less instructions IIRC, but the `%` ahead of registers, the weird (machine like) memory addressing syntax, and reversed order of operands annoy me too much, I prefer Intel syntax, even if occasionally the explicit specifiers are needed, but for churning out several lines of x86 assembly I feel lot more comfortable with Intel syntax. (just chit chatting about personal bias, I'm not trying to convince you to switch, use whatever you like :) ).

Comment: @Ped7g I'm mostly dealing with GCC/etc. assembler output, so, switching to Intel is too cumbersome in my case. I'm comfortable with AT&T except some cases when reverse argument order causes mess, as in `shld`. Other issues are both weird for AT&T and Intel; I'd rather see "sxt eax,ax" instead of remembering all these crappy `cwd`/`cwde`/`cdq`/etc, the same as `cltq`/`cltd`...